# Extract Specific Raster Cells From Gridded Shapefile

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, cursor, extract-by-mask

I have a raster image with a corresponding shapefile grid in which I am looking to extract an individual piece of that image using a single grid of the entire shapefile. The gridded shapefile is ordered sequentially from 0...*n* in the column FID. The code I was currently working with to loop through this process is as follows:

```
outws = r"C:/folder_with_resulting_extraction/"
raster = r"C:/somefolder/rasterfile.tif"
fc = r"C:/somefolder/fishnet_clipped.shp"

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
count = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["FID", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        out = os.path.join(outws, "outraster" + str(count) + ".tif")
        ebm = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask (raster, row[1])
        ebm.save(out)
        count = count + 1

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

I would preferably like to modify or execute this script such that I would extract the corresponding raster from any `FID` number in the shapefile I specify (example would be 65). I had originally had this in a `while` loop, however the search cursor would start the extract at `FID = 0` in the shapefile regardless of where the `count` was initiated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will extract from the raster based on a specified `FID` value, the `fldValue` variable.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
import os

outws = r"C:/folder_with_resulting_extraction/"
raster = r"C:/somefolder/rasterfile.tif"
fc = r"C:/somefolder/fishnet_clipped.shp"
fs = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, 'selectLayer')

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

fldName = arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName
fldValue = 65

where = ''' "{0}" = {1} '''.format(fldName, fldValue)

out = os.path.join(outws, "outraster" + str(fldValue) + ".tif")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fs, "NEW_SELECTION", where)
ebm = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(raster, fs)
ebm.save(out)

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

Comment: Jacob F, I appreciate the help with the code! From the use of `SelectLayerByAttribute`, I assume that I'll need to make the shapefile I have into a feature layer, correct?

Comment: No, it works fine with a shapefile.

Comment: Perfect, it must be a user error type situation on my end! When I end up running the script at an arbitrary number I threw in, I get the following errors that pop up in terminal: `arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.`
`The value cannot be a feature class`
`ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.`
`ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.`
`Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).`

Comment: These specifically fired on line 28 of the script: `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", where)`

Comment: I've updated the code to resolve this error.